# C coding for anagrams (how to ignore periods)

Tags: c

This is the code I have so far for coding for anagrams. Everything seems to be right except for some reason, while it doesn't count apostrophes it does count periods, making some things which should be anagrams, not. How do I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h> 

#define MAX 25 
#define LETTERS 26 

void initialize(int * letters, char * string1, char * string2); 
void setletters (char string1[], int letters[]);
void checkletters (char string2[], int letters[]);
char *getstring(char s[]);  
int isZero(int letters[]); 


int main(void)
{ 
    int letters[LETTERS]; 
    char string1[MAX]; 
    char string2[MAX]; 
    while(1){
        initialize(letters, string1, string2); 
        getstring(string1); 
        setletters(string1, letters); 
        getstring(string2); 
        checkletters (string2, letters);  


        if (isZero(letters)) 
            printf("Anagram \n \n");
        else
            printf("Not an Anagram \n \n");
    }
    return 0;
}


void initialize(int * letters, char * string1, char * string2)     
{
    int count = 0; 
    for(; count < LETTERS;  count++)
    {
        letters[count]= 0;
    }

    for(count = 0; count < 25;  count++)
    {
        string1[count]= '\0';
    }

    for( count = 0; count < 25;  count++)
    {
        string2[count]= '\0';
    }

    return; 
}



char * getstring(char string1[])
{ 
    char * errorcheck; 
    printf("Enter line:  "); 
    errorcheck = gets(string1);
    if (errorcheck)
        return string1; 
    return NULL;            
}

void setletters (char string1[], int letters[]) 
{
    int count,
    numletter = 0;

    for(count = 0;(count < MAX) ; count++)
    {    
        if(isalpha(string1[count])) 
        {
            string1[numletter] = tolower(string1[numletter]);
            numletter =(int) (string1[count] - 'a');
            letters[numletter] = (letters[numletter] + 1);
        }
    }

    return;
}

void checkletters (char string2[], int letters[]) 
{
    int count,
    numletter = 0;

    for(count = 0;(count < MAX) ; count++)
    {    
        if(isalpha(string2[count])) 
        {
            string2[numletter] = tolower(string2[numletter]);
            numletter = (string2[count] - 'a');
            letters[numletter] = (letters[numletter] - 1);
        }        
    }
    return;
}


int isZero(int letters[]) 
{ 
    int numletter = 0;

    for(; numletter < LETTERS; numletter ++)
    {
        if (letters[numletter])
            return 0; 
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both `setletters` and `checkletters`, you have a block like:

```
if(isalpha(string1[count])) 
{
    string1[numletter] = tolower(string1[numletter]); // <==
    numletter =(int) (string1[count] - 'a');
    letters[numletter] = (letters[numletter] + 1);
}
```

`numletter` is supposed to be the offset of the letter from `a`, but you are using it to index into `string1`. You intended to use `count` in both places.